# Is it possible that Lily Luna Potter could have been sorted into Hufflepuff?

Tags: harry-potter

This might seem impossible in the Potter family, but Albus was sorted into Slytherin! So chances aren't that slim, are they? Could Lily have possibly ended up in Hufflepuff?

Comment: Or Ravenclaw maybe :p

Comment: I'm unsure why this has received a close vote, especially since this is directly answerable from canon sources.

Comment: I flagged because I interpreted "is it possible...could have been" as a hypothetical (answers for which are going to boil down to opinion/speculation), not an invocation of canon. Happy to concede that it's answerable with canon if interpreted as such, which I see one answer has done. Bellatrix's answer below is good, well-written and well-sourced, but it does just boil down to "it depends on X and Y qualities (for which we have no canon evidence)", which to me is not the mark of a good question.

Comment: I was asking because in my fanfic on Wattpad, Julia Longbottom, Albus Potter, and Scorpius Malfoy think about that. I put her into Hufflpuff because earlier in the story I described her as a kind, patient soul. She gets sorted into Hufflepuff in my story and can relate to Julia, Scorpius, and Albus problems. I think it was absolutely possible, but I wanted opinions first.

Comment: @SophiaReynolds Ah, I understand now! Well, I think it’s absolutely possible, including in canon! :) I’ll find her quotes from the epilogue for you.

Comment: @TheWalrus469 "Not the mark of a good question" is not the same as "primarily opinion-based".

Comment: _Everybody_ can be sorted _wherever_.

Answer (score 5):

## It would depend both on her personality and House preferences.

Whether it’s possible for Lily Luna Potter to be Sorted into Hufflepuff would depend on both her personality, and whether she’d want to be a Hufflepuff. If she’s loyal and kind, then it’d be at least possible for her to be in Hufflepuff, even if she doesn’t *actually* end up there, since the Sorting Hat sometimes considers more than one House for a student before deciding on one, especially if the student doesn’t fit just one House perfectly (like Draco and Tom Riddle did).

Harry could have possibly been in Slytherin, and perhaps one of the other Houses as well. Even though he ended up in Gryffindor, it was definitely *possible* that he might not have.

> “Hmm,’ said a small voice in his ear. ‘Difficult. Very difficult. Plenty of courage, I see. Not a bad mind, either. There’s talent, oh my goodness, yes – and a nice thirst to prove yourself, now that’s interesting … So where shall I put you?’
>
> Harry gripped the edges of the stool and thought, ‘Not Slytherin, not Slytherin.’
>
> ‘Not Slytherin, eh?’ said the small voice. ‘Are you sure? You could be great, you know, it’s all here in your head, and Slytherin will help you on the way to greatness, no doubt about that – no? Well, if you’re sure – better be GRYFFINDOR!” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 7 (The Sorting Hat)*</sup></sub>

The Sorting Hat found Harry a difficult case, and it was most likely Harry’s personal preference that influenced his final decision on Harry’s placement. Saying “Not a bad mind either” implies the Sorting Hat might have been considering Ravenclaw as well, for at least a moment.

Lily Luna Potter said two things during the epilogue. She was impatient to go to Hogwarts, and wanted to go that same year.

> “Two large cages rattled on top of the laden trolleys the parents were pushing; the owls inside them hooted indignantly, and the red-headed girl trailed tearfully behind her brothers, clutching her father’s arm.
>
> ‘It won’t be long, and you’ll be going too,’ Harry told her.
>
> ‘Two years,’ sniffed Lily. ‘I want to go now!” 
> <sub><sup>*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Nineteen Years Later - The Epilogue*</sup></sub>

She also wanted Teddy Lupin, Harry’s godson, to marry Victoire Weasley and officially become part of the family.

> “Oh, it would be lovely if they got married!’ whispered Lily ecstatically. ‘Teddy would *really* be part of the family then!” 
> <sub><sup>*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Nineteen Years Later - The Epilogue*</sup></sub>

Both of these seem like things that a kind and loyal Hufflepuff could easily and plausibly say, so there’s certainly no reason to rule out the possibility she’d be considered for Hufflepuff.

<sub>*If we’re willing to venture outside of the seven books, there’s also a Pottermore writing by JKR explaining Hatstalls, which are students who the Sorting Hat took more than five minutes to choose their House.*</sub>

> <sub>The Sorting Hat spent nearly four minutes trying to decide whether it should place Hermione in Ravenclaw or Gryffindor. In Neville’s case, the Hat was determined to place him in Gryffindor: Neville, intimidated by that house’s reputation for bravery, requested a placing in Hufflepuff. Their silent wrangling resulted in triumph for the Hat.</sub>
>
> <sub>The only true Hatstalls known personally to Harry Potter were Minerva McGonagall and Peter Pettigrew. The former caused the hat to agonise for five and a half minutes as to whether Minerva ought to go to Ravenclaw or Gryffindor; the latter was placed in Gryffindor after a long deliberation between that house and Slytherin.</sub>
> <sub><sup>*[Hatstall (Pottermore)](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/hatstall)*</sup></sub>

<sub>*According to that, then it was certainly possible for Hermione, Neville, McGonagall, and Pettigrew to be in different Houses than they were actually placed in.*</sub>

## There are precedents to family members having different Houses.

Even though she’s a Potter, and often the members of a family end up in the same House so that would predispose her to be in Gryffindor (especially since she’d be both a Potter and a Weasley, both Gryffindor families), it’s still possible she’d be at least considered for another House.

Sirius Black was Sorted into Gryffindor, despite being a Black when most of them go to Slytherin.

> “Well, anyway, he was a big pal of your father’s at school. The whole Black family had been in my house, but Sirius ended up in Gryffindor! Shame – he was a talented boy. I got his brother Regulus when he came along, but I’d have liked the set.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 4 (Horace Slughorn)*</sup></sub>

The Patil twins also ended up in different houses.

> “Er – yeah, all right,’ said Harry. He turned back to Hermione, Ron and Nearly Headless Nick. ‘Brothers and sisters usually go in the same houses, don’t they?’ he said. He was judging by the Weasleys, all seven of whom had been put into Gryffindor.
>
> ‘Oh, no, not necessarily,’ said Hermione. ‘Parvati Patil’s twin’s in Ravenclaw, and they’re identical, you’d think they’d be together, wouldn’t you?” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 12 (The Triwizard Tournament)*</sup></sub>

So, it’s possible to actually be put in, not just considered for, another House than your family members.

Comment: +1 from the Bright side! :D That's a well-reasoned answer!

Comment: @HarryWeasley Thanks a lot! :D You’re pretty cool for a Weasley! :P

Answer (score 2):

Technically yes, Lily could have been Sorted into Hufflepuff - anyone can technically land in any House. For more on that angle, see @Bellatrix's answer.

However, no, she couldn't be Sorted into Hufflepuff because...

**She's a Gryffindor.**

We see in the fanfiction<sup>1</sup>*Harry Potter and the Cursed Child*, Act 1, Scene 4:

> SORTING HAT: Are you afraid of what you'll hear?
>   Afraid I'll speak the name you fear?
>   Not Slytherin! Not Gryffindor!
>   Not Hufflepuff! Not Ravenclaw!
>   Don't worry, child, I know my job,
>   You'll learn to laugh, if first you sob.
>   Lily Potter. GRYFFINDOR.
>   LILY:  Yes!

<sub><sup>1</sup>Okay, it's canon. Ugh.</sub>

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question of “would it be possible for Lily to be sorted into Hufflepuff?” this answers the question “what house was Lily L Potter sorted into?”

Comment: I'd say that answering the latter question would answer the first, by saying "no, she's already been Sorted into a different House". Anyway, I've edited.

Comment: No it doesn't. The question is asking about the hypothetical, whether or not she could've ended up there. Not whether she had ended up there. Harry got sorted into Gryffindor, but he could've been sorted into Slytherin (or so I'm told)

Comment: +1 for terming the Cursed Child fanfiction!

Comment: @HarryWeasley High five from the Dark side! :D

Comment: -1 for terming the Cursed Child canon!